# Access the querystring in a Spiffy app

Tags: scheme, chicken-scheme, spiffy

One shouldn't have to ask this here, but thanks to the bad documentation, how do I access the querystring in a Spiffy (egg) app? Thanks!

```
(use intarweb spiffy sxml-serializer) 

(tcp-buffer-size 2048)
(server-port 80)

(handle-not-found (lambda (path)    
    ; (print (request-uri (current-request)))
    ; (print (request-method (current-request)))
    ; (print (current-pathinfo (current-request)))
    ; (print (current-file))
    ; (print (remote-address))
    (send-response 
        body: (serialize-sxml
            `(div (@ (class "page"))
                (h1 ,path))
            method: 'html))))

(start-server)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure why you want to access the query string, but the
URI objects in Spiffy come from the request object, as you've correctly
identified.  The request object is from intarweb, which sticks an
uri-common object in the `request-uri` attribute.

You can access the constituent component parts using uri-common's
accessors, as documented in the [URI-common egg reference](http://wiki.call-cc.org/eggref/4/uri-common#accessors)

The query string is parsed into an alist for your convenience, and
accessible through `(uri-query (request-uri (current-request)))`.

The "original" query string can be accessed a little more differently:
the uri-common egg is a convenience wrapper around the lower-level egg
uri-generic, which you can access by calling `(uri->uri-generic URI)`,
where URI is `(request-uri (current-request))`, as before.

Then, you can access the query string through the `uri-query` procedure
from that egg.  Here's a simple example you can use on the REPL:

```lisp
#;1> (use uri-common (prefix uri-generic generic:))
#;2> (uri-reference "http://foo?x=y")
#<URI-common: scheme=http port=#f host="foo" path=() query=((x . "y")) fragment=#f>
#;3> (uri-query #2)
((x . "y"))
#;4> (uri->uri-generic #2)
#<<URI>>
#;5> (generic:uri-query #4)
"x=y"
```

What I did here is prefix all the procedures from uri-generic with
"generic:".  This is necessary because uri-common "shadows" all the
procedures defined by uri-generic.